# How to parse a json using es6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have below json as input

```
result = [
    {
        "category": "Social Media",
        "sub_category": "Facebook"
    },
    {
        "category": "Social Media",
        "sub_category": "Instagram"
    },
    {
        "category": "Tech",
        "sub_category": "Angular"
    },
    {
        "category": "Tech",
        "sub_category": "Javascript"
    }
]
```

i am trying to acive below json

```
{
  "Social Media": [
    "Facebook",
    "Instagram"
  ],
  "Tech": [
    "Angular",
    "Javascript"
  ]
}
```

Below code i tried to active this. Could anyone please help where i am doing wrong

```js
let result = [{
    "category": "Social Media",
    "sub_category": "Facebook"
  },
  {
    "category": "Social Media",
    "sub_category": "Instagram"
  },
  {
    "category": "Tech",
    "sub_category": "Angular"
  },
  {
    "category": "Tech",
    "sub_category": "Javascript"
  }
]
let data = [];
let categorySet = new Set();
result.forEach((val, key) => {
  categorySet.add(val.category);
});

result.forEach((val, key) => {
  let subCat = new Set();
  categorySet.forEach((v, k) => {
    if (v == val.category) {
      let d = {};
      d[val] = subCat.add(val.sub_category);
      data.push(d)
    }
  })
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has actually nothing to do with es6, but here is the code that could help:

```js
const data = {}

let result = [{
    "category": "Social Media",
    "sub_category": "Facebook"
  },
  {
    "category": "Social Media",
    "sub_category": "Instagram"
  },
  {
    "category": "Tech",
    "sub_category": "Angular"
  },
  {
    "category": "Tech",
    "sub_category": "Javascript"
  }
];

result.forEach((value) => {
  data[value.category] = data[value.category] || []
  data[value.category].push(value.sub_category)
});

console.log(data);
```

Not sure, why you wanted to use a `Set`, because a `Set` more close to an array, but what you want to get as a final result is an object

Comment: i am using Set because it will not add duplicate data

Comment: @SangramBadi, to use a `Set`, change the first line in `forEach` function to assign `new Set()` instead of `[]` to `data[value.category]` and it'll be fine

Comment: It also has nothing to do with JSON or parsing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy), try this example

```js
result = [
    {
        "category": "Social Media",
        "sub_category": "Facebook"
    },
    {
        "category": "Social Media",
        "sub_category": "Instagram"
    },
    {
        "category": "Tech",
        "sub_category": "Angular"
    },
    {
        "category": "Tech",
        "sub_category": "Javascript"
    }
]

var groupJson= _.groupBy(result, function(result) {
  return result.category;
});
console.log(groupJson);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would give the expected output:

```js
let result = [{
    "category": "Social Media",
    "sub_category": "Facebook"
  },
  {
    "category": "Social Media",
    "sub_category": "Instagram"
  },
  {
    "category": "Tech",
    "sub_category": "Angular"
  },
  {
    "category": "Tech",
    "sub_category": "Javascript"
  }
];

let data = {};
result.forEach((row) => {
  if (!data[row.category]) {
    data[row.category] = [];
  }
  if (!data[row.category].includes(row.sub_category)) {
    data[row.category].push(row.sub_category);
  }
});

console.log(data);
```